# Need to run ReadyAPI using maven project with jenkins as CICD approach

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui, ready-api

Run the ReadyAPI project using maven with help of jenkins.

I have already created a regression suite in readyAPI as xml format.
Created a java maven project using pom.xml
jenkins job has been created to run the ReadyAPI suite directly but want to run using the java project which include pom.xml

Run the ReadyAPI project using maven with help of jenkins.

Need to provide some videos in which i can solve the issue which i am currently facing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The ReadyAPI - Maven integration documentation is here https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/maven/index.html Exactly what problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to split this question into two concerns:

- How do you call Maven from Jenkins?

And once you've got that, you need to think about...

- How do I run a SoapUI/ReadyAPI project from Maven?

The first question is addressed here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pts8zdHel5E

The second question is addressed here:
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/maven/example.html

If you have already covered the basics here, and got some specific problem, you need to provide more information to your specific situation.